# Android BroadcastReceiver to check when a SMS has been sent / delivered

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

Being new to Android Development, I decided to make an Application that could replace the standard SMS Application on your Android Phone.

I want to be able to send and receive SMS Messages. I already implemented those parts, but there are some problems with the part of sending the SMS Messages.

My SendSms method looks like this:

```
public void sendSms(String fullNumber, String messageText) {
    String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
    String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";
    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(
            SENT), 0);
    PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
            new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(fullNumber, null, messageText, sentPI, deliveredPI);

    allDates.add(date2);
    itemsSent.add(messageText);
    sent.add(false);
    delivered.add(true);
    clamb.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

clamb is a CustomListAdapter:

```
clamb = new CustomListAdapterMessageBody(this, itemsSent, number,
            allMessages, allDates, sent, delivered);

    setListAdapter(clamb);
```

- number: the number of the person.
- allMessages: an Array of messages you sent to the person + messages the person sent to you (all messages).
- itemsSent: an Array of messages you sent to the person. This way I make a distinction between Sent / Received messages. By doing this, I can change the way messages are being put in the ListView: Received Messages will have a red arrow, sent messages will have a green arrow.
- allDates: an Array of all dates of the messages.
- sent: an Array with true / false values to check if a message has been sent.
- delivered: checks if the message is delivered.

To check if a message is being sent or delivered, I'm using a BroadcastReceiver.
The code looks like this:

```
sendBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            switch (getResultCode()) {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                // Message is sent proparly
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
                ContentValues cv2 = new ContentValues();
                cv2.put("address", fullNumber);
                String date2 = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
                cv2.put("date", date2);
                cv2.put("read", 1);
                cv2.put("type", 2);
                cv2.put("body", messageText);
                getContentResolver().insert(uri, cv2);

                if (!sent.isEmpty()) {
                    int size = sent.size();
                    sent.clear();
                    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                        sent.add(i, true);
                    }
                    clamb.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                Toast error = Toast.makeText(context, "Generic Failure",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                error.show();
                setDeliveredFalseAndSentTrue();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                error = Toast.makeText(context, "No Service",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                error.show();
                setDeliveredFalseAndSentTrue();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                error = Toast.makeText(context, "Null PDU",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                setDeliveredFalseAndSentTrue();
                clamb.notifyDataSetChanged();
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                error = Toast.makeText(context, "Radio off",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                error.show();
                setDeliveredFalseAndSentTrue();
                break;
            }
        }

        private void setDeliveredFalseAndSentTrue() {
            if (!sent.isEmpty()) {
                sent.set(sent.size() - 1, false);
                clamb.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            // Sms is delivered
            if (!delivered.isEmpty()) {
                int size = delivered.size();
                delivered.clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    delivered.add(i, true);
                }
                clamb.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    };

    deliveryBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            switch (getResultCode()) {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                // Sms is delivered
                if (!delivered.isEmpty()) {
                    int size = delivered.size();
                    delivered.clear();
                    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                        delivered.add(i, true);
                    }
                    clamb.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                break;
            case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
        }
    };
```

Now.. If I send an SMS, the CustomListAdapter will not show a green / red arrow. It will show a small clock first. After that, it will either show a green arrow (if the message is sent proparly) or it will show a red cross (if the message hasn't been sent proparly).

BUT! The sms is being stored INSIDE the BroadcastReceiver. When I send an SMS and I immediately close the Activity, the BroadcastReceiver won't store the SMS, because there's no time. (The BroadcastReceiver stops functioning when the Activity stops.

How should I handle this problem best?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is always advisable to do the things which take time inside a `Service` instead of doing in  `Broadcastreceiver`. I would suggest to start a `Service` from `Broadcastreceiver`

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer, Green Goblin. I've never worked with services before, so I'll look into that!

Comment: Do you mean I should do something like this: 

       `sendBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

             @Override
             public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                   startService(new Intent(context, SendSmsService.class));
             }
        }`
Because I think this won't solve my problem. In this case, the service will only be called when the BroadcastReceiver's onReceive method is called. When I send a SMS and I close the activity instantly, the BroadcastReceiver's onReceive method will never be called => The Service will not be started?